# PTIJ: Halacha regarding the expression: "Let's be in touch"

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

How is it Mutar for a man to tell a woman (or vice versa), "Let's be in touch"?
Doesn't this violate the Halachos of Shomer Negiah?
And if this is merely an expression, it seems like lying.
What's P'shat?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a form of lying. There are numerous ways that you can touch people without the hands.

You can send a woman a nice complimentary letter or a meaningful D'var Torah or something that will make her happy. Better yet, tell a woman how much you love her and how much she means to you and that she improves your life. All of these are ways to touch a woman's heart. Really, now, unless you're planning on doing surgery, you don't actually touch someone's heart with your hands!

I'm not going to ask if you're married or single. Not my business. (Well, OK .. if you are single, I may have a great girl for you!) But, As a married man, myself, I can tell you that these things work well.

Comment: That is the problem youre Jewish and  you talk English and you expect it to be ok. If you would use the Hebrew version you wouldnt have a problem.

Comment: @interested What are you talking about?